# iOS performSelector onThread with object

Tags: ios, performselector

Is it possible to use this method and pass an object?  With this code, I get this error:

```
-[myApp hideUpdateView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b6a880
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[myApp hideUpdateView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b6a880'
```

It never reaches the hideUpdateView method...

Code:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil];
[self performSelector:@selector(hideUpdateView) onThread:[NSThread mainThread] withObject:array waitUntilDone:YES];



- (void) hideUpdateView: (NSArray *) inputArray
{
    int catCount = [[inputArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
    //hide it
}
```

Comment: I've been off iOS development for a while, but should it be `@selector(hideUpdateView:)`?

Comment: @H2CO3 Coolness. And I haven't written a line of Obj-C in like 2 years. I should have put that in as an answer instead to earn points.

Comment: stupid mistake, got it.  thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the colon from the end of the selector name. (Please, read an Objective-C turorial. The colon is part of the name of the selector.)

```
[self performSelector:@selector(hideUpdateView:) onThread:[NSThread mainThread] withObject:array waitUntilDone:YES];
                                              ^
                                     Note the colon here
```

Comment: oh man thanks guys stupid mistake.  that did it.  So you have to have the ':' when the method you are calling has parameter(s)?  because most of my normal performSelector calls dont have the ':' and it works fine.

Comment: @userXXX yes. Every parameter needs a colon. Consider the name of `@selector(performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:)` itself...